# How to fix VS Code "live share" extension not responding to clicks

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-liveshare

I installed Live Share in VS Code but it is not showing me the login window, instead a tab for it appeared which has 2 buttons but they are not responding.

[image: Here is the image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today. I'm not sure what causes this error but as suggested in a related [VSCode issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/180#issuecomment-644317254) I used the repair command that comes with the Live-Share extension:

- Open VSCode's command prompt:

  `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`
- Enter the following command:

  `>Live Share: Repair Installation`
- Follow further instructions

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 22.04, issue is reported [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/4646):

A solution/workaround is as follows (from [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/4646#issuecomment-1115120608)):

```bash
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libssl1.1
```

Comment: I've got `Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]`

Comment: This solution worked for me, with a slight modification. I'm pretty sure that, at least on Ubuntu 22.04 now, the above will result in: 
`E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

You need to change `security` to `old-releases`, resulting in:
`echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list`

As mentioned, this has security implications.

Answer (score 3):

For Manjaro (possibly also Arch) `icu69` was missing. Installing it sorted it for me. (It stopped working out of the blue after an update - not really sure why - probably some dep that changed somewhere...)

Comment: Fixed the issue for me on arch as well.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and solved it by installing some missing package on linux.
[linux-tips-by-distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/linux#tips-by-distribution)
See this site if you run vscode in linux too.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Macbook with M1 chip, I tried the other answers but they didn't work and the solution for my case was to install rosetta software (seems like liveshare depends on some Intel specific things till now)

So in the terminal, just run:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Live Share plugin doesn't have the Linux dependencies installed it can fail silently. This presents as there being no way to sign in to Live Share and the buttons in the question seemingly not working.

In my experience this was the problem when I used an Alpine Linux base image for the Devcontainer. By Switching to a recent Ubuntu base container and rebuilding my Devcontainer (and GitHub Codespace), followed by the above answer of reparing the installation it worked.

I recognise I could have spent time figuring out the missing dependencies, but it was quicker for me to just change the base image, YMMV.

To summarise

```
1) Ensure the base image in the Dockerfile to one supported by Live Share such as Ubuntu
2) Repair the installation using the command pallet
```

**References**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/linux
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers